# How to add a virtual hard disk as a portable(external) storage media in virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to practice cloning hard drive *(say HDD X)* using Clonezilla through Virtualbox. I have successfully done all steps. However I need a storage media of atleast size of HDD X.

I can do it by attaching an external hard drive and mounting it as a usb device.

However, I want to perform it without using a physical drive. Is there a way that I can create a portable hard drive virtually and mount it in virtual machine as a usb device.